# How to create an Outline on generated objects with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, geometry

Creating an outline effect on an object is kind of simple with a backface-material assigned to a duplicate of the object with a position set to an offset by the normals:

[image: Geometry nodes]

It also works if I create a primitive node (here a cylinder) instead of using an object from the scene:

[image]

But if I create an object with "String to curve" and duplicate it to a 3x3 grid of objects, rotate them individually, and then try to apply the offset by normal it stops working:

[image]

It doesn't matter what value I scale the normal vector with, the "position"/"resized by normal" stays on top of the unaltered geometry with the SolidColor-material. Anyone have any idea why the Normal-offset applied to "Set position" breaks?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put a *Realize Instances* node before the *Set Position* for it to function properly.

[image]